# Charge renormalization using Ward identity

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, renormalization, feynman-diagrams, ward-identity

In Mandl & Shaw's Quantum Field Theory (p 181), the Ward identity
$$\frac{d\Sigma(p)}{dp_\mu} = \Lambda^\mu(p,p)\tag{9.60}$$
where $\Sigma(p)$ and $\Lambda^\mu (p^\prime,p)$ are respectively the modified electron propagator and the modified vertex, is used to show that the charge renormalization from the vertex correction and the electron self-energy are the same. First, they express the modified electron propagator $$\Sigma(p) = A +(p_\mu \gamma^\mu -m)B + (p_\mu \gamma^\mu-m)\Sigma_c(p)\tag{9.26}$$
where $A$, $B$ are infinite and $\Sigma_c$ is finite and represent the radiative corrections.

They then calculate
$$\bar{u}(p) \frac{\partial \Sigma(p)}{\partial p_\mu} u(p)\tag{9.61}$$
and they show that it is equal to $B\bar{u}(p) \gamma^\mu u(p)$. The term $(p_\mu \gamma^\mu -m)\frac{d\Sigma_c(p)}{dp_\mu}$ disappears as $\bar{u}(p)(p_\mu \gamma^\mu -m) =0$. They state that
$$\Sigma_c(p)u(p)=0\tag{p.192+197}$$
but I don't understand why they can assume this.

Could somebody explain me where this relation comes from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer lies in the fact that

> $\Sigma_c(p)$ vanishes linearly with $(\gamma^{\mu}p_{\mu}-m)$ as $\gamma^{\mu}p_{\mu}=m$

according to the text after Eq. (9.26). This implies that

$$\Sigma_c=C (\gamma^{\mu}p_{\mu}-m)+...$$

for some constant $C$. Hence,

$$\bar{u}(p)\frac{\partial\Sigma(p)}{\partial p_{\mu}}u(p)=
\bar{u}(p)\frac{\partial}{\partial p_{\mu}}\Big[
A+(\gamma^{\mu}p_{\mu}-m)B+(\gamma^{\mu}p_{\mu}-m)\Sigma_c(p)
\Big]u(p)\\
=\bar{u}(p)\Big[
\gamma^{\mu}B+\gamma^{\mu}\Sigma_c(p)
\Big]u(p)\\=
\bar{u}(p)\Big[
\gamma^{\mu}B+C\gamma^{\mu}(\gamma^{\nu}p_{\nu}-m)
\Big]u(p)\\=
B\bar{u}(p)\gamma^{\mu}u(p)$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is $\Sigma_c$ a power series of $(\gamma^\mu p_\mu -m)^n$ or just a term containing $C (\gamma^\mu p_\mu -m)$ and additional terms?

Comment: The text does not specify to be honest. If it is the second case, well one must be cautious not to include contributions, such are the ones diverging as $\gamma^{\mu}p_{\mu}=m$ [like $1/(\gamma^{\mu}p_{\mu}-m)$], or even constant terms etc... So this is restrictive enough such that it points you to the first case, i.e. $\Sigma_c$ being a power series of $(\gamma^{\mu}p_{\mu}-m)$